# Origin does not execute my script

Tags: scripting, originlab

I'm trying to execute the following LabTalk script in Origin:

```
for(ii=1; ii<=4; ii++)
{ 
string iiString$ = $(ii)    
newbook name:="iiString" sheet:=1 option:=lsname
}
```

I just paste it into Script Window and hit "enter" on my keyboard and nothing happens. I tried also putting a semicolon after:

first row; all text rows; rows in the loop; any of rows.

I also tried version with intended rows that are inside the loop. What may be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for calling the string variable is not correct. If you use `iiString$` instead of `"iiString"` it works fine:

```
for(int ii=1; ii<=4; ii++)
{ 
  string iiString$ = $(ii)    
  newbook name:=iiString$ sheet:=1 option:=lsname
}
```